# How to sync directory within Vagrant box (virtualbox provider) with local directory?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine

I have used the vagrantfile provided in [this here tutorial](https://antonio-maiolo.com/2016/12/01/web-crawler-scrapy-crawl-spider-tutorial/) and can't seem to get my local files synced to the VM. I tried `mkdir vagrant_data` and that didn't show them in there. What do I do?

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant_data"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.gui = false
     vb.memory = "2048"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be giving the wrong file path of the host machine. Instead of giving the `./` relative path which could refer to anything. Try using the absolute path instead. Here if the [Official tutorial](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html#configuration) on how to configure.